# NetCDF-C++: How to build it?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, netcdf, netcdf4

I would like to use the NetCDF API in my **C++ projects.**

In the offical web site documentation, I saw that this C++ interface have a **compilation dependency of NetCDF-C library.**

I already downloaded binary NetCDF-C installer (called `netCDF4.7.1-NC4-DAP-64.exe`) from the offical website ([link here](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/index.jsp)) installed it and add the installed folder to my `PATH`.

```
C:\Program Files\netCDF 4.7.1\
```

So I tested it in the Windows console runing: `ncdump.exe` ...**and all works good!**

Now I cloned the NetCDF-CXX4 repository [(link here)](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4) and tried to compile it, **but I got a lot of CMake errors.**

**My system is:**

- Windows 10 x64
- Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise
- CMake 3.14.4
- NetCDF-CXX 4.3.1

### What I did

Inside the cloned NetCDF-CXX4 folder, I created a folder called "build".
Inside the `build` folder I typed: `cmake ..`

### Here is the console error

```
 cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.23.28105.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.23.28105.4
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.23.28105/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found bash: C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/bash.exe
-- Looking for nc_use_parallel_enabled in netcdf
CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeLists.txt:17 (add_executable):
  Target "cmTC_7cc31" links to target "hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/cmake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CheckLibraryExists.cmake:67 (try_compile):
  Failed to generate test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:382 (CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/lamar/Desktop/netcdf-cxx4-4.3.1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

**What I have to do to build the NetCDF-CXX4 static/dynamic libraries in my system?**

Comment: Building this library on Windows is not *officially* supported, according to one of their developers (see [here](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4/issues/33#issuecomment-394434248)).

Comment: `Target ... links to target "hdf5::hdf5-shared" but the target was not found.`- It seems that CMake cannot find HDF5 library. Do you have this library installed?

Comment: `hdf5` is a common library on Linux systems (a simple `yum install hdf5` if it isn't already installed on your system). Windows is a different animal, however. Since the prebuilt [binaries](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/) only target VS14/VS15, you'll likely need to build for VS16 from source by downloading it [here](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/source-code/).